# Changing Storage class from Multi-Regional to Coldline in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I just finished my 1 year free trial with Google Cloud Platform and I am now being billed.

When I set my first project up, it looks like I set it up as Multi-Regional.  I would only use the Google Cloud Storage in the event of a catastrophic failure in my home where i lose data on both internal and external hard drives (ie. fire, etc) .  I believe for this type of backup, I only need Coldline storage.   I did change my project over to Coldline but it looks like it only changes new data, not the original stored data because I am still being charged for Multi-regional storage.

From what I understand, I have to change the Object Storage Class either by overwriting the data using `"gsutil rewrite -s [STORAGE_CLASS] gs://[PATH_TO_OBJECT]"` or by Object Lifestyle Management.  I could not figure out how to do either, so I need help doing this (I am not even sure where to type these commands or which approach to use (I am not a programmer!!)).

I also saw in another post that my gsutil command needs to up to date 4.22 or higher.  How do I check this??  I also saw in this post that the [PATH_TO_OBJECT] is My Bucket.  I see a Project Name, Project ID, and Project number.  Which of these (if any) are used in that field for My Bucket?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also saw in another post that my gsutil command needs to up to date
>   4.22 or higher. How do I check this??

Get the gsutil version:

```
gsutil version
```

Update the Cloud SDK which includes gsutil:

Windows:
Open a command prompt with Administrator rights

```
gcloud components update
```

Linux:

```
gcloud components update
```

> I see a Project Name, Project ID, and Project number. Which of these
>   (if any) are used in that field for My Bucket.

Use the PROJECT_ID.  To get a list of the projects that you have access to. This command will list each project.

```
gcloud projects list
```

To see which is your default project:

```
gcloud config list project
```

If the default project is blank or the wrong one, use the following command.

To set the default project:

```
gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]
```

> From what I understand, I have to change the Object Storage Class
>   either my overwriting the data

Assuming your bucket name is `mybucket`.

STEP 1: Change the default storage class for the bucket:

```
gsutil defstorageclass set coldline gs://mybucket
```

STEP 2: Change the storage class for each object manually. This is an option if you want to just select a few files.

```
gsutil rewrite -s coldline gs://mybucket/objectname
```

STEP 3: Verify the existing lifecycle policy. Change step 4 accordingly if an existing policy exists.

```
gsutil lifecycle get gs://mybucket
```

STEP 4: Change the lifecycle of the bucket. This policy will move all files older than 7 days to coldline storage.

POLICY (write to lifecycle.json):

```
{
    "lifecycle": {
        "rule": [
        {
            "action": {
                "type": "SetStorageClass",
                "storageClass": "COLDLINE"
            },
            "condition": {
                "age": 7,
                "matchesStorageClass": [
                    "MULTI_REGIONAL",
                    "STANDARD",
                    "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"
                ]
            }
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Command:

```
gsutil lifecycle set lifecycle.json gs://mybucket
```

Comment: I got through step 1 after a few problems which I figured out.  So the default storage class for my bucket is now coldline.  I don't think I need to do step 2 since I want my entire bucket to be coldline (but I am not sure because I do not know what an object is).  In step 3, I was told my bucket has no lifecycle configuration so I went on to step 4.  Do I type in the policy as you presented it using all those brackets etc. on different lines??   If so, after I type that in, do I type in the Command you show after it, gsutil lifecycle set lifecycle.json gs:// mybucket???

Comment: Copy and paste into a file, don't hand type the json. The CLI does not care if the json is one huge line, however if you get an error messages it is much easier to debug if the json is formatted. Yes, use the command line that I gave you changing the bucket name. An object is a file stored in a bucket.

Comment: I apologize for being so ignorant to programming commands, etc.  If I copy and paste the above Policy into the administrative command prompt,  I get all sorts of error messages about unrecognized commands.  You said in last post to paste into a file.  I am not sure where that should be done.  It does look like the change to coldline storage has occurred on my bucket so do I even need to do step 4??  I thought from my original reading on the subject that you do one or the other (gsutil to rewrite data OR using lifecycle manangement).  Thanks for your help BTW!!!

Comment: As I show in my answer: `POLICY (write to lifecycle.json):`

Comment: If I type: Policy (write to lifecycle.json): in the administrative prompt, I get error messages so I don't think that is what I should be doing.  Sorry, I am not a programmer, I am a veterinarian so this is all new to me.

Comment: I did do a rule change in the console to change the bucket to coldline from yesterday and older.  It does show up in a command promt: C:\WINDOWS\system32>gsutil lifecycle get gs://cloudberrybackup-jwreveley
{"rule": [{"action": {"storageClass": "COLDLINE", "type": "SetStorageClass"}, "condition": {"createdBefore": "2019-03-01", "matchesStorageClass": ["COLDLINE"]}}]}     Is this doing the same thing as with a json Policy?

Comment: The `matchesStorageClass: COLDLINE` does not look correct. Go back to the Google Cloud Console and edit your policy. You want objects that are NOT coldline to be changed to coldline. Your policy says if coldline change to coldline which is like a `placebo` in your field.

Comment: How does this look?  C:\WINDOWS\system32>gsutil lifecycle get gs://cloudberrybackup-jwreveley
{"rule": [{"action": {"storageClass": "COLDLINE", "type": "SetStorageClass"}, "condition": {"createdBefore": "2019-03-03", "matchesStorageClass": ["MULTI_REGIONAL"]}}]}      I think we have it so I thank you for all your help!!!  Just confirm for me that it is correct.

Comment: Take a look at the policy that I created. Notice that "matchesStorageClass" has three storage classes. In the Google Cloud Console, just click on the three storage classes to move to coldline.

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>gsutil lifecycle get gs://cloudberrybackup-jwreveley
{"rule": [{"action": {"storageClass": "COLDLINE", "type": "SetStorageClass"}, "condition": {"createdBefore": "2019-03-05", "matchesStorageClass": ["MULTI_REGIONAL", "STANDARD", "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"]}}]}   I think we have it!!!!!   Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @JohnReveley To indicate that your question has been answered, you need to click the gray checkmark in the margin of the answer you found most helpful. Moderators cannot do this for you; only the person who asked the question can select an answer. For more help, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers